How to separate last child folder from path in Pascal Script?
I need to separate last child folder from Windows path. For example from C:\java_11 separate java_11. I have this function:
function parseJavaHome(JavaHome:String) : String;
var lastPosOfSlash: Integer;
var tmp : String;
var slash: char := '\';
var vCharacter : char ;
var counter: Integer := 0;
begin

   for vCharacter in JavaHome do
   begin
      counter := counter + 1;
      if vCharacter = slash then
      begin
      lastPosOfSlash := counter;
      end;
   end;

   for i:= lastPosOfSlash to Length(JavaHome) do
   begin
       tmp := tmp + JavaHome[i];
   end;

   Result:= tmp;
end;

But compilation fails on line 1224:
var slash: char := '\\';

It returns me this error:

Error on line 1224 in C:\Users\pkostrou\IdeaProjects\packstation_adm_core\installer\build\adm-application-setup.iss: Column 21:
Semicolon (';') expected.
Compile aborted.


Use ExtractFileName support function:
https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_extractfilename

As for your code, it has many problems. In general, your code is for Delphi, but this is a Pascal Script.
